# Laravel not sending mail to random users from Database

Tags: laravel

My mail controller works fine but does not send to random users in the database.

I am sending a custom email from laravel application. The application has a "send to all" function will sends the email to all users in the database. This function send the email but some times randomly skips users.

Ex. first send - everyone receives mail
Second send - user with id 3 does not receives 
Third send - user with id 3 receives but user with id 15 does receives 
Forth send - everyone receive mail

I have tried to hard code the user id in the mail controller and it works for user id 15 but not for user id 3.

I have not setup Exception Handling following this tutorial https://laravel-news.com/email-on-error-exceptions with no luck.

```
Exception Handler
<?php
// sending email
    try {
        $e = FlattenException::create($exception);

        $handler = new SymfonyExceptionHandler();

        $html = $handler->getHtml($e);

        Mail::to('my@email.co.za')->send(new ExceptionOccured($html));
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        dd($ex);
    }
?>

Send To Controller
<?php
Mail::to($applicant[0]->email, 'Applicant Registration Details')
    ->send(new BulkMailNotification(
        $applicant[0]->id,
        'Stellenberg Feesmark 2',
        $applicant[0]->name,
        $applicant[0]->surname,
        $applicant[0]->status,
        $applicant[0]->language,
        'null',
        $mail_template_details,
        'this is the mail body',
        NULL,
        $temp,
        'email@account.co.za'));
?>

Notification Handler
<?php

public function build()
{

    return $this->from($this->sent_from_email, 'User')
        ->subject($this->mail_template['mail_subject'])
        ->view($this->mail_template['lang_template'])
        ->text($this->mail_template['lang_template']);

 }
?>
```

The above functions should send out mails to all users seleceted in DB and email me if any error occurs during mailing process.

Comment: unless it reached a fatal error like `Timeout`

Comment: I don't think sending an email to yourself is the best idea if your emails stop working?

Comment: @KyleWardle : I want to be able to get a notification when the error occurs and thus I am sending mail to my self. I thought that this will help me debug what the cause is.

Comment: @SiphiwoJulayi In this use case it is probably ok but for example, if the mail server stops working, you wont get an email. I would not rely on sending an email to tell me an issue about if my emails are working or not.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that you are sending the emails, sometimes users are not receiving it but you are not receiving an email to say it hadn't worked? In which case I would look at things like the mail server logs to see if any emails are being throttled, rejected etc. It might be a good idea to use a service like Mailgun or Mailtrap just to see if all of the emails are actually being "sent". If so then it is not a coding issue.